# SAS - Changing Existing Character Variable values to Numeric using Input

Tags: sas, type-conversion

Have a variable called var1 that has two kinds of values (both as character strings). One is "ND" the other is a number out of 0-100, as a string. I want to convert "ND" to 0 and the character string to a numeric value, for example 1(character) to 1(numeric).

Here's my code attempt:

```
data cleaned_up(drop = exam_1);
    set dataset.df(rename=(exam1=exam_1));
select (exam1);
    when ('ND') do;
        exam1 = 0;
    end;
    when ; 
        exam1 = input(exam_1,2.);
    end;
    otherwise;
end;
```

Clearly not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to add a comment, I have no idea what to put in that second when statement that can make it like when (0-100) since 0-100 aren't numeric...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of problems with your code.  Putting the `rename` statement as a dataset option against the input dataset will perform the rename before the data is read in.  Therefore `exam1` won't exist as it is now called `exam_1`.  This will still be defined as a character column, so the `input` function won't work.

You need to keep the existing column, create a new numeric column to do the conversion, then drop the old column and rename the new one.  This can be done as a dataset option against the output dataset.

The `tranwrd` function will replace all occurrences of 'ND' to '0', then using `input` with the `best12` informat will read in all the data as numbers.  You don't have to specify the length when reading numbers (i.e. `2.` for 2 digits, `3.` for 3 digits etc).

```
data cleaned_up (drop=exam1 rename=(exam_1=exam1));
set df;
exam_1 = input(tranwrd(exam1,'ND','0'),best12.);
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using select(exam1) while it should be select(exam_1). You can use select for this purpose, but I think simple **if** condition can solve this much easier:

```
data test;
    length source $32;
    do source='99', '34.5', '105', 'ND';
        output;
    end;
run;

data result(drop = convertedValue);
    set test;

    if (source eq 'ND') then do;
        result = 0;
    end;
    else do;
        convertedValue = input(source,??best.);
        if not missing(convertedValue) then do;
            if (0 <= round(convertedValue, 1E-12) <= 100) then do;
                result = convertedValue;
            end;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

**input(source,??best.)** tries to convert **source** to number and if it fails (e.g. values contains some word), it does not print an error and simply continues execution.

**round(convertedValue,1E-12)** is used to avoid precision error during the comparison. If you want to do it absolutely safely you have to use something like

```
if (0 < round(convertedValue,1E-12) < 100
    or abs(round(convertedValue,1E-12)) < 1E-10 
    or abs(round(convertedValue-100,1E-12)) < 1E-10
)
```

Comment: Are there any potential issues with using ?? that the OP should be aware of as well?

Comment: Hi, I do not know about any potential issues when using '??' modifier. It will not print a message for invalid values and will not set an automatic ERROR variable. I guess if the OP wants to see the invalid values, another **else** condition can be added to handle the case when convertedValue is missing and one more in case the number is outside the 0-100 range.

Comment: I choose the other answer because the code was succinct from a readability standpoint. But this is also a nice answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use ifc function then convert to numeric variable.

```
data have;
input x $3.;
_x=input(ifc(x='ND','0',x),best12.);
cards;
3
10
ND
;
```